# Drawing 2 Squares Side by Side

Tags: c++

I've been racking my brain trying to get my head around this problem. Basically I have to take 2 inputs and then draw 2 squares side by side using the inputted value. For example if a user enters `5` and `3` the output should look like this:

```
XXXXXYYY
XXXXXYYY
XXXXXYYY
XXXXX
XXXXX
```

The `x` square is 5x5 and the `y` squre is 3x3.

So far I am only able to make the shapes one at a time, using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int a, b;
cout << "a and b: ";
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
int c;

for (int r = 1; r <= a; r++){
  for (int c = 1; c <= a; c++){
    cout << "x";
  } // col a
  cout << endl;
} // row a

for (int r = 1; r <= b; r++){
  for (int c = 1; c <= b; c++){
    cout << "y";
  } // col b
  cout << endl;
} // row b


} // main
```

However I end up with something like this:

```
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
yyy
yyy
yyy
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I'll give you a bit of a hint because I think you're doing well. You're getting it backwards because you're using two different for-loops. You end up with what you have because you're printing all of the X and then the Y. You can do this all in one for-loop. Start with just the row. Think about what you need to print and use an if/else statement to print your x or y.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int a, b, h;

    std::cin >> a >> b;
    h = std::max(a, b);

    for ( int i = 0; i <  h; ++i )  {
        for ( int j = 0; j < a; ++j )
            std::cout << ( ( i < a ) ? 'x' : ' ' );
        if ( i < b )
            for ( int j = 0; j < b; ++j )
                std::cout << 'y';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```